# Find a TR by ID and attribute name with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hi All I'm working on a web app and I'm trying to find a specific TR using a few criteria.

To keep my code short, here's what it looks like, it's a combination of Razor and HTML but I'm trying to keep this to a minimum....

```
<tr id="someId" someAttribute="Attribute1" otherAttribute="Attribute2">
```

My jQuery looks like this:

```
function GetTRValue(){
   var tr = $('tr[id=someID]:visible');   <-- This works great.

}
```

This works, and if I look in debugger I can see my attributes.

However what I am trying to achieve is to get this `TR` using `ID` and `someAttribute` - because I want to get the value of `otherAttribute`

```
function GetTRValue(){
   debugger;
   var attributeValue = 'Attribute1';
   var tr = $('tr[id=someID] [someAttribute=' + attributeValue + ']:visible');   <-- This doesn't work
   console.log(tr);
}
```

I've also tried to **scrape** :visible all together (even thought I need to use it)

```
function GetTRValue(){
   debugger;
   var attributeValue = 'Attribute1';
   var tr = $('tr[id=someID] [someAttribute=' + attributeValue + ']');   <-- This doesn't work either
   console.log(tr);
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
 function GetTRValue(){
   debugger;
   var attributeValue = 'Attribute1';
   var tr = $('tr[id=someID] [someAttribute=' + attributeValue + ']');   <-- This doesn't work either
   //By now I should have the correct tr

   var otherAttribute = tr.attr('otherAttribute'); 
}
```

Anyone can provide guidance. Thanks.

Comment: @isherwood also, there will be mulitple TR's with the same ID. However, someAttribute and otherAttribute are dynamically assigned (as this is razor code). Therefore the goal is to find that specific TR with someAttribute= dynamically assigned Attribute Name which I will have

Comment: Remove the space in your selector. Space means "descendant" in jQuery just as in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had two mistakes:

1. A misspelled ID (ID/Id)
2. A space in your selector between attributes, implying a child relationship

```js
var attributeValue = 'Attribute1';
var tr = $('tr[id=someId][someAttribute=' + attributeValue + ']:visible');
tr.addClass('hightlight');
```

```css
.hightlight {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="someId" someAttribute="Attribute1" otherAttribute="Attribute1">
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="someId" someAttribute="Attribute2" otherAttribute="Attribute2">
    <td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```